# Delayed 'Update' Message Insertion in MSSQL Broker: Troubleshooting and Resolution

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I employ MSSQL 2019 triggers for 'insert,' 'update,' and 'delete' operations and utilizing MSSQL Broker to generate messages for consumption as audit messages. Each message triggers a specific row insertion into a designated table.

Recently, I've observed a substantial delay in the insertion of records triggered by 'update' operations. For instance, upon updating a record in a table, the audit row insertion into the log table takes approximately 30 seconds, while the intended record insertions are not happening promptly. This delay appears to be confined to one specific database, with other databases of identical structure not exhibiting this behavior.

How can I efficiently troubleshoot and address the delay specifically related to 'update' messages? Are there established solutions to resolve this issue? Additionally, considering multiple databases with similar setups, how can I factor in these differences when resolving this problem?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the execution plan for the `UPDATE` statement in the (presumably) activated proc. Add code for the trigger and proc to your question if you need further help.